# Taking continous input through loop in php

Tags: php, loops, input

Actually, I want to write a program of taking numbers as input continously and to stop taking input when suppose the input is 42, and then display the input numbers.

I tried the if condition but it takes only one input and displays it.

Comment: what do you mean be taking inputs?

Comment: what did you try so far? let us see your related code so we can help better.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously a loop wouldn't work if you're using plain PHP.

I suppose you could set something up where you use a form, set the action attribute to the same page, and keep each number in a global variable array; when the sentinel number is set, print the list of numbers in the cookie instead of the form when the page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

take input & store it in array unless it is 42 .to check use if loop.

```
eg:
 $num = 'take input value' ;
 if( $num == 42) {
    foreach($numbers_info as $number)
       echo $number;
 }else {
    $numbers_info $numbers_info[] = $num;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try writing a class something like this:

```
class trackNumber{
  private static $instance = null;
  protected $numbers = array();

  private function __construct()
  {
  }

  public static function getInstance()
  {
    if (!self::$instance) {
      self::$instance = new trackNumber();
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }

  public function addNumber($number) {
    if ($number < 42 ) {
      $this->numbers[] = $number;
    }
  }

  public function getNumbers()
  {
    return implode(', ', $this->numbers);
  }
}   

$myNumbers = array(1,3,5,6,8,9);

$trackNumbers = trackNumber::getInstance();

foreach($myNumbers as $number) {
  $trackNumbers->addNumber($number);
}

?>
```

---

```
<?php 
echo $trackNumbers->getNumbers(); 
// result will be: 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9  
?>
```

You can add as much checks and functions as you'd like. Due to this being a singleton you can always add or retrieve the numbers anywhere.